# Kafka streams BigDecimal Serde

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use kafka-streams API to aggregate **BigDecimal** values and publish it to a log compacted topic.
I have a problem with output value serde.  Can someone suggest how should i go about the output value serde?

The snippet is given below:

```
KStream<String, String> sourceStream = streamBuilder.stream("source-topic");

sourceStream.map((key, value) -> {
    ...
    return keyValue;
})
.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> new BigDecimal("0.0"), (key, value, sum) -> sum.add(value))
.to("target-topic");

//.to(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, ???, "target-topic");
```

The exception is as given below:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=2_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000014, topic=source-topic, partition=0, offset=0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:238) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.process(AssignedTasks.java:409) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:308) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:939) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:819) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:771) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:741) [kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: java.math.BigDecimal). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:91) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:222) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:91) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:78) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:211) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:222) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.2.jar:?]
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your own Serde implementation?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you. Time being I changed the value to be a string and so used a string serde.

Comment: Okay. I think that would work best for languages outside of Java